# Quick Sort Python

Tags: python

I just started learning python. I received an error trying to implement Quick Sort into my program. TypeError: recQuickSort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'last'. Personally, I don't think there's anything wrong with it because I acquired it from my school's lecture. The only problem I'm facing is how to implement it to sort a dictionary. How do I go about calling the function?

Below is my code:

```
# Quick Sort

# Sorts an array or list using the recursive quick sort algorithm
def quickSort(theSeq):
    n = len(theSeq)
    recQuickSort(theSeq, 0, n - 1)


# The recursive "in-place" implementation
def recQuickSort(theSeq, first, last):
    # Check the base case (range is trivially sorted)
    if first >= last:
        return
    else:
        # Partition the sequence and obtain the pivot position
        pos = partitionSeq(theSeq, first, last)
        # Repeat the process on the two subsequences
        recQuickSort(theSeq, first, pos - 1)
        recQuickSort(theSeq, pos + 1, last)

# Partitions the subsequence using the first key as the pivot
def partitionSeq(theSeq, first, last):
    # Save a copy of the pivot value.
    pivot = theSeq[first] # first element of range is pivot
    # Find the pivot position and move the elements around the pivot
    left = first + 1 # will scan rightward
    right = last # will scan leftward
    while left <= right:
    # Scan until reaches value equal or larger than pivot (or right marker)
        while left <= right and theSeq[left] < pivot:
            left += 1
    # Scan until reaches value equal or smaller than pivot (or left marker)
        while left <= right and theSeq[right] > pivot:
            right -= 1
        # Scans did not strictly cross
        if left <= right:
        # swap values
            theSeq[left], theSeq[right] = theSeq[right], theSeq[left]
        # Shrink range (Recursion: Progress towards base case)
            left += 1
            right -= 1
    # Put the pivot in the proper position (marked by the right index)
    theSeq[first], theSeq[right] = theSeq[right], pivot
    # Return the index position of the pivot value.
    return right
```

Comment: You haven't posted the part with the bug. Show us something that actually reproduces the error when run, as well as the *complete, exact* error message, including full stack trace.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jazzl/Desktop/Data Structures & Algorithms/PythonDSA.py", line 214, in <module>
    market = sort_menu(market, recQuickSort)
  File "C:/Users/jazzl/Desktop/Year 2 Sem 1/Data Structures & Algorithms/PythonDSA.py", line 103, in sort_menu
    second_list = sort_type(second_list, 'Price')
TypeError: recQuickSort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'last'

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your code, and it is working fine (Python 2.7.16 here).

Here is an example on how to call you function:

```
a = [3,2,1]
quickSort(a)
# [1, 2, 3]

b = [10,9,8,7,1,2,3,4,5]
quickSort(b)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Obs.: I do not receive the error you mentioned.

Comment: What if I want to use my own elements of the dictionary? How do I go about returning the function and calling it?

Comment: You have to implement some mechanism on how to compare two dictionary, to the algorithm know how to order the items. I'm not a specialist in python but in java you would implement method equals and comparable. I suppose in python you have to do something like that too.